# standard deviation of multiple vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, standard-deviation

I have multiple vectors of length N, and I want to calculate the standard deviation (Std) of them, so if I have these vectors:

```
[1.03132, 1.456758,1.1324684]
[0.46546, 3.232658,3.1456444]
[0.21346, 0.568748,1.5554487]
```

The standard deviation vector is:

```
[0.34198709 1.10748961 0.86669951]
```

If I want the final value as a single value rather than a vector, can I calculate again the Std of the produced vector again!?

Is this the right way to deal with vectors to get the Std ?! if no, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The standard deviation measures how far from the average something is.

If you take the standard deviation of the entries of your result vector, you'll get a number that indicates how far each coordinate's standard deviation is from the average of your result vector's coordinates.

So for instance, if you result vector were something like $v =[10,10,10]\,$ (meaning your input vectors have high variance) and you took the standard deviation of the coordinates of $v$, you'd get $0$.

In short, I don't think this is a good measure.

Comment: but how could I achieve that in a right way ?!

Comment: I don't know. That depends on what you want.

Comment: I want a final value, that can uniquely represents the Std of a set of vectors?

Comment: That is not very specific. There are plenty of bijections $\mathbb R^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ but I'm pretty sure this is not what you want. What properties do you want this final value to have? How do you want to use it?

Comment: I have a set of vectors is a space, each represent a sentence .. So, I want to detect special pattern using Std of the sentences' distribution

Comment: What does each coordinate represent? You could take the $\max$ of coordinate std's I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75267/discussion-between-mib-minion-and-fimpellizieri).

Comment: So this isn't a good measure - fair enough. But what *is* a good measure of variance for an array of vectors then?